# How to make my website first page is a login page in joomla like joomla administrator?

Tags: php, joomla

I am a novice in joomla. Now I use joomla to make a website , and I need the the website first page is a login page(login form) , only users registered will see other pages.(like joomla admistrator)

I have looked for others similar articles, 
 [change default joomla login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764550/change-default-joomla-login-page),
 but I still have a little confused, 
  my template default entry is index.php  and it has  other associated components and menus. 
 How to set the default page is login?

and I also know that I should setting up access level of all my menu items as registered.

Will you have any good suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**a:**
You could use the lockdown feature of Joomla usually used for closing the site.

**System > Global Configuration > tab - Site**

**Site Offline = Yes**

Then save and logout and look at the front of your joomla site. You will just see a login box which you may want to style.

This is a little of a hack way to do it quickly

**b:** this is the suggested way 
You should mark all your menu items with the **Access : "Registered"**

Then make a second home page and mark this **Access : "Guest"**

You then put any content you like on this new page and **a login module box.**

This way people not loged in will see the Guest page and all when logged in will see Registered pages. For example if you had a menu on the page all the links will now show in the menu when logged out they did not, as Guest does not have permission.

Is this what you want?

Comment: Thanks! I have tried the meathod a , it works. And I also try the meathod b, use if($user->get('guest')){//need to login} to check whether the current user need to login or not , and determine to switch to second home page(login page) or stay the default index.php. This also worked! Thanks~